# ADO.NET Entity Data Model auto generated code violates Code Analysis CA2214

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, visual-studio-2012, code-analysis

In a MVC 3 solution, under VS 2012, it sounds strange that you receive such message after Running Code Analysis:

[image]

It is strange because the class which is mentioned in the "DON'T" analysis was generated by VS itself (not me).

To reproduce this you can:

1. add **ADO.NET Entity Data Model** to your solution,
2. add your database tables (already existent in SQL Server) to your diagram,
3. rebuild solution, add Controllers and cshtml views (those ones are generated automatically).
4. run the code analysis from ANALYZE menu.

So, the question is, what could we do: Refactor the auto-generated code or ignore this message?

Below a sample of auto generated class which violates the rule CA2214:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//    This code was generated from a template.
//
//    Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//    Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Backoffice.Entities
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class BR_SIMUL_Supermarket_Product
    {
        public BR_SIMUL_Supermarket_Product()
        {
            this.BR_SIMUL_Supermarket_Product_Price = new HashSet<BR_SIMUL_Supermarket_Product_Price>();
        }

        public int product_id { get; set; }
        public int category_id { get; set; }
        public string product_name { get; set; }
        public string product_measure { get; set; }
        public bool product_active { get; set; }
        public virtual BR_SIMUL_Supermarket_Category BR_SIMUL_Supermarket_Category { get; set; }
        more stuff here...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design to allow for lazy loading. When you access the classs through `DbContext` it won't fail at run-time despite the warning. You should suppress the warnings only in those files.

Comment: What do you do when suppressing the warning is not an option? My company will not allow any critical warnings in FxCop.

Comment: @chill182 You should exclude auto-generated code from FxCop / StyleCop.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I solved it permanently: http://chuckbeasley.com/blog/?p=42200

Answer (score 1):

You should feel free to suppress these. Take a look at this [discussion](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/400154) on the Entity Framework codeplex site for more details.